# Run a loop for each result in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT @var:= meta_value, @no:=post_id FROM tbl WHERE `meta_key` ="_wpbdp[fields][10]"
```

now this gets around 500 results..
I want to run another `INSERT` query for each value of `@var` and `@no` variable.

Example::

```
 INSERT INTO tbl ('value','id') VALUES (@var,@no);
```

How do i get this in a LOOP??

Comment: Won't a `INSERT...SELECT` work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop, and btw, these variables will always hold just one value.

```
INSERT INTO tbl(`value`, `id`)
SELECT meta_value, post_id FROM tbl WHERE `meta_key` = "_wpbdp[fields][10]";
```

Also note, that this

```
INSERT INTO tbl ('value','id')
```

is wrong, because with `'` you make `value` and `id` strings, not column names.

Read more about possible `insert` syntaxes [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).

Comment: ok, i used the following code, but it says syntax error, pls suggest the error?
SELECT meta_value, post_id FROM `yr8tu_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = "_wp_attached_file"
INSERT INTO `yr8tu_posts`(`ID`,  `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES (,Replace(meta_value,".jpg",""),,"publish","open","open",,Replace(meta_value,".jpg",""),post_id,"","0","attachment","image/jpeg","0")

Comment: Please read my answer again, it says `insert into tbl(col1, col2) select col1, col2 from tbl`, not `select col1, col2 from tbl insert into...`. I added the official syntax in my answer.

Comment: Because you have no `;` between your statements. So MySQL thinks that it's one statement, but a `SELECT ... INSERT` doesn't exist.

Comment: Also you have a comma too much here: `VALUES (,`

Comment: So does it work now? If yes, feel free to accept my answer by clicking the check to the left of my answer, so that others now that the issue is solved.

Comment: no, it still gives error. from the mysql documentation i learned VALUES need not be used here, but still cant fix it completely.

Comment: I'm confused now, what query you're actually using. Edit it into your question.